# ColdFusion Variable Name with brackets

Tags: forms, coldfusion, cfml

I'm interacting with a webhook which provides a FORM struct with several variables containing brackets `[ ]` . How can I utilize these variables within CFML?

Example:

```
FORM.PAYLOAD[SITE][ID]
```

`FORM` is the struct
`PAYLOAD[SITE][ID]` is the name of the variable within the `FORM` struct.

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `#form['PAYLOAD[SITE][ID]']#` will treat the whole value as the key to look for

Comment: The answer provided by Matt-Busche resolved my issue I was having. Thank you sir! (I clicked the arrow for your comment - I hope it helps others).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather suggest you to dump the `form` struct using `cfdump` like this-

```
<cfdump var = "#form#" />
```

and see if `PAYLOAD[SITE][ID]` is a key of `form` struct or only `payload` is the key.

If the whole `PAYLOAD[SITE][ID]` appears as a key in the dump, then as @matt suggested, you can utilize the variables like this-

```
<cfset payload_site_id = form["PAYLOAD[SITE][ID]"] />
```

Answer (score 1):

ColdFusion does not natively handle structs or arrays within a forms.

In 2007, Brian Kotek created a tool that do that processing.

In 2013, I created a tool that worked with the then current version of FW/1 . The latest version of that tool can be found at: https://github.com/jmohler1970/BS-4-CF/tree/master/framework

Last but not least, I put in a ticket into Adobe bugbase to add that functionality natively: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=4156093