# Coldfusion/Lucee How to output this variable containing brackets [] in the name?

Tags: coldfusion, x-editable, lucee

I'm using this x-editable plugin (https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/demo-bs3.html) and specifically the "Custom input, several fields" located towards the bottom of the demo.

First, everything is working just fine on the implementation but I'm struggling with how to save the submitted data (see screen shot below further down). I don't know how to reference value[address1] in my sql statement without Lucee thinking its a structure (I hope that makes sense in what I'm trying to say here). When I try to reference the variable reports via `writeDump(form.value[address1])`, Lucee provides me the following error:

`key [value] doesn't exist`

[image: screen shot of writedump(form)]

How do I reference form fields in the image? Should I change how the data is being submitted perhaps using  [jQuery's serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method?

Comment: Just found this SO so I'm trying it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40034108/coldfusion-variable-name-with-brackets

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] which shows exactly what you are asking about.

Answer (score 2):

It was much easier than I thought. I didn't even know you could do this!

`local.address1 = form['value[address1]'];`

Thanks to the comment made by @Matt-Busche in the SO question,  [ColdFusion Variable Name with brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40034108/coldfusion-variable-name-with-brackets).